# How do I configure an nginx AWS ECS container with an nginx.conf file

Tags: docker, nginx, config, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a dotNet application in one container and an nginx image in another container.  The nginx image is an already configured image, using an nginx.conf which is built and uploaded to aws ecs to be included into task definitions.  The tasks definition is set up with fargate.

This works fine.

Rather than having to regularly update the image and re-upload it for each task definition, I should like to change the ecs task definition to use the nginx:latest image direct from docker.

What I cannot work out is how to configure that image with my nginx.conf file in the task definition.  Can anyone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy the official Nginx docker image, without making any changes to the image, then you will have to configure it by having an `nginx.conf` file in a folder that gets mounted into the container. Since you are using Fargate, the only option for doing this, at this time, is to create an [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) volume, put your nginx.conf file in that volume, and then configure your ECS task to [mount the volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/tutorial-efs-volumes.html) into your Nginx container.

Comment: I'll have a look into that, thank you.